# Angular 2 Redirect from Routing Module, Root to child

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I would like to redirect a route from my routing Module. I have an "empty shell  component" which will have many children inside. Is something like this on my main component for this Module ( Project Module ):

```
<app-project-nav-bar></app-project-nav-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

At this module routing I have:

```
const PROJECT_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ProjectComponent, children: [
    { path: `${CLIENT_PATHS.PROJECT}`, component: ProjectInformationComponent},
    {...}
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(PROJECT_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProjectRoutingModule {
}
```

And my Main Routing Module:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module#HomeModule', canActivate: [ IsLoggedGuard ] },
  { path:  ':id', loadChildren: 'app/project/project.module#ProjectModule', canActivate: [ IsLoggedGuard ]},
  {...},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

What I would like to do is, when reaching the root for my Project Module, redirect it to its child, so the user would't land on this empty shell, something similar to what I do at the Main Module with: `{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }`. I was hoping to do like this at my Project Module Routing:

```
const PROJECT_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ProjectComponent, redirectTo: `:id/${CLIENT_PATHS.PROJECT}` ,children: [
    { path: `${CLIENT_PATHS.PROJECT}`, component: ProjectInformationComponent},
    {...}
  ]}
];
```

But nothing seems to work to redirect to the child.
I don't want to use the "shell component" to redirect, because looks to me it not the right way to do it. Does anyone knows how to do it from the Route Class?

Comment: `' '` empty route definition cannot load a child module, so create another child definition with a non empty path and associate the child module to it.

Comment: It's not really empty, the root definition is `:id` defined at APP_ROUTES, which is the main routing module. By doing that I can load my child components with no problems and do the Lazy Load. The issue is that I cannot hardcode a path to redirect, because my root path is dynamic, and thats is a requirement :/